# Broken Pipe C with sendfile on socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to recode a FTP server in C.

I open a data socket to my client (PASV), and when it try to do RETR on a valid file, I use `sendfile` from the file asked to the data socket:

```
int fd;
struct stat s;

if (cmd->arg && (fd = open(cmd->arg, O_RDWR)) != -1)    
{
    fstat(fd, &s);
    if ((size = sendfile(client->data_soc, fd, NULL, s.st_size))
        == -1)
       perror("sendfile failed:");
    else
       printf("datas sended\n");
       close(client->data_soc);
}
```

Client is a structure containing the data socket `client->data_soc` already open, and cmd is the client's command, containing the name of the  file to open `cmd->arg`, which is a `char *`.

The problem is when I do it, the `sendfile` function stop with `SIGPIPE`.

I really don't understand why, I think I use it correctly, and I can't find any solution to this issue in particular.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which OS, which libc please?

Comment: When I read "*broken pipe*" in the context of writing to a socket, I tend to say the receiver disconnected.

Comment: I'm using Linux (Deepin 15.4), what you you mean by "which libc" ? The receiver disconnected because of the server crash, I use netcat to test it

Comment: libc is part of the C implementation. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc version 6.2.0 20161103 (Debian 6.2.0-11) for the compiler, and the glic 2.24

Answer (score 0):

This happens because:

1) the client closed the connection in the middle of the transfer; and
 2) the system is configured to raise a signal instead of returning the EPIPE error.

So you need to fix both the client and the server: the client must not close the connection in the middle and the server must be robust against client abuse.

Use, for example, sigprocmask() to disable SIGPIPE.

Comment: Thanks, but I just connect netcat on the socket to receive datas, I don't think the client close the connection in the middle